# It is possible train a neural network for soccer players prediction?

Tags: neural-networks, python, tensorflow, keras

I have a large number of players stats, such as goals, assist, meters run, passes, etc.. of 3 seasons. I would like to know if I can feed the Neural Network with the data and it will return the best player of the season. My objective is that with the data the N.N gives me the best player of the season.

I already built an N.N that makes soccer predictions, however, when training I was giving the match result. In this case, it is different, because I'm not giving the information of who was the best player.

If it is possible, what structure should I use and how should I prepare the data?

Comment: What kind of task would this model perform? Given a set of stats of several players, choose the best one of them? On what data would this network be trained? How would you verify that its predictions are correct?

Comment: You have to define what is the best player of the season. Is it the one that scored most goal? As @JanKukacka said, try to define more precisely the task and how you can test it.